# SSIS: Input columns not returning for PostgreSQL ODBC Connector

Tags: ssis, odbc

Basically, on the ODBC Source, i can see the tables, i can preview the data, but i when i click on the columns menu nothing is returned and i cant save the ODBC Source with the selected source.
I'm using:

- PostgresSQL 15.0;
- SSIS 2022;
- ODBC Driver psqlodbc_15_00_0000-x64, but i've tryed the 32bits too;
- EC2 with linux from AWS;

1. I can see the tables:

[image]

2. I can Preview the data:

[image]

3. But when i click on the columns menu, the columns don't show up, without any errors

[image]

My ODBC Connection:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tested A LOT of versions of the ODBC driver and for all versions the ANSI and the Unicode option and none of this works.

Edit:

- The ADO.NET conection works, but is EXTREMELY SLOW;
- We used to have a MySQL database on the server and the same problem was happening, but we can't see a connection why this is happening;

  - Maybe is some king of catalog issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We "discovered" how to fix it downgrading the SSIS version to the version 2015.